# Does Hessian have a timeout?

Tags: java, php, spring, hessian

Does the Hessian protocol have a timeout?

Note: I am not using Hessian4J. Instead, I am using Spring for exporting the Hessian services and my own code for handling Hessian request.

Comment: and instead you're using which implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caucho's site is down (*as usual*) so I can't check the official Java implementation's documentation, but [this page for a PHP library](http://hessianphp.sourceforge.net/) states:

> The protocol uses HTTP as transport by sending and receiving POST requests to remote services.

Because it's HTTP-based, there are a few places where timeouts will come in to play even if the binary protocol itself doesn't have the concept of a timeout.  This means that the remote server may decide to terminate the connection if it's taking too long, or the local client may do the same.  Changing this depends on configurations on both sides.

---

I was finally able to [check the specs](http://hessian.caucho.com/#Documents), and found nothing mentioning timeouts expressly.